# how to create connection between Odoo 10 and pycharm?

Tags: python, odoo, pycharm

Recently I installed Odoo 10 on my laptop. 
But there is no openerp-server file in Odoo 10.

How do I create connection between Odoo-10 and pycharm?

I have tried open-erp but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new file in odoo 10 is `odoo-bin`

read the [docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/cmdline.html) about it